# Does anyone here have experience developing for Minix?

Tags: minix

Recently I have become curious about the Minix OS. http://www.minix3.org/

I am very taken with descriptions of its robustness & reliability features, but I have noticed a distinct paucity of software packages available for the platform.

Has anybody here developed software for (or ported software to) Minix? Anything unexpected about the process?

Answer (score 6):

Minix 3 is a new version; LINUX was prompted on the original Minix.

Minix is really best suited to small systems of embedded systems.  If you have an old x86 PC around it should run minix handily, giving you an environment very much like what we called "an amazing workstation" in the mid-80's.

I loved programming in that environment; I'd say go for it, but remember that it is an experimenal environment, not what you want for your day-to-day system.

Answer (score 4):

Coded round robin scheduler and such with nano, SSH connection can be used to code in new fashion platforms and send back the files. Minix is a great way to learn basics about Operating Systems.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this piece while finding out how to contribute to minix. I liked it:
http://prasannakumartsm.wordpress.com/